# Django - join two query sets by id?

Tags: python, django

Im trying to join two tables together before being sent to a view, using _set in a view causes 100s of queries which is highly inefficient.

example structure sites.models.py

```
class SiteData(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    site_type = models.ForeignKey(SiteTypes, verbose_name="Site Type", \
                on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    bgp_as = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name="BGP AS Number")
    opening_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Site opening date")
    last_hw_refresh_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of latest hardware refresh", \
                           blank=True, null=True)
    is_live = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is this a live site?")
```

example structure config.models.py

```
class SiteSubnets(models.Model):
    site_data = models.ForeignKey(SiteData, verbose_name="Location", \
                on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)               
    subnet = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', \
             verbose_name="Subnet", blank=True, null=True)
    subnet_type = models.ForeignKey(SubnetTypes, verbose_name="Subnet Type") 
    vlan_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Vlan ID", blank=True, null=True)
    peer_desc = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Peer description", blank=True, null=True)
    site_ip = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is this a site supernet IP?")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Site Subnets"
        verbose_name_plural = "Site Subnets"
```

Queries:

```
site_subnets = SiteSubnets.objects.only('subnet').filter(site_ip=True)
site_data = SiteData.objects.only('location','is_live','bgp_as','postcode','opening_date','live_link_type')
```

Desired Outcome example:

```
Location   | Subnet     | BGP AS
---------------------------------
London     | 10.10.10.0 | 65001
Manchester | 10.10.20.0 | 65002
...
```

I cant do a select_related without having the SitesSubnet table as the main table, as when I do it on site data, I get

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'site_subnets'. Choices are: site_type
```

If I use the SiteSubnet as the main table, if a Site does not have a SiteSubnet.site_up I wont get the Site info. displayed

does anyone know a way around this that will display all the data and not run n+1 queries?

EDIT:

prefetch also fails with the below error:

```
AttributeError: Cannot find 'site_subnets_set' on SiteData object, 'site_subnets_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()
```

I would be sending the data to a template to be accessed in a loop i.e

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>Subnet</td>
    <td>BGP AS</td>  
  <tr>
{%for site in sitedata %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ site.location }}</td>
    <td>{{ site.subnet }}</td>
    <td>{{ site.bg_as }}</td>  
  <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you use `SiteData.objects.prefetch_related('sitesubnets_set')`? That should prevent n+1 queries if you run `site_data.sitesubnets_set.all()` in a loop.

Comment: How are you displaying it? you could do a for loop on your site_subnets queryset, and access the SiteData from each element...

Comment: You didn't try what I suggested. You used `site_subnets_set` instead of `sitesubnets_set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prefetch_related` to prefetch sitesubnets for the sitedata queryset.

```
SiteData.objects.prefetch_related('sitesubnets_set')
```